# How to get pivot data in laravel lighthouse?

Tags: laravel, graphql, laravel-lighthouse

I use lighthouse package for making my graphql schema (https://github.com/nuwave/lighthouse)

But how to get data from `@belongsToMany` relationship that is stored in pivot table?

E.g. the `Document` entity connected N-N to `Person` entity. And each Person has some meta data in the pivot table.

```
foreign_citizens: [Person!] @belongsToMany(relation: "foreignCitizens"),
```

Answer (score 0):

At first you need to get your pivot data in laravel using `withPivot` at the end of the relation, sth like this:

```
public function foreignCitizens(): BelongsToMany
{
  return $this->belongsToMany()->withPivot(/* here is a list of your pivot data */);
}
```

Then you need to define the appropriate `type` in graphql:

```
type ForeignCitizenPivot {
  # Here goes the same list again
}
```

Then add a `pivot` to your `ForeignCitizen` type in graphql again:

```
type ForeignCitizen {
  # other attributes
  pivot: ForeignCitizenPivot 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's simple data, I like to use model accessors. So, for example, you could add something like this to the model for your metadata.

```
function getMetaDataItemAttribute() {
    return $this->pivot->meta_data_item;
}
```

Then in the Graph Schema, if it was a string, for example, you can reference it as a direct property.

```
type ForeignCitizen {
    # other attributes
    meta_data_item: String 
}
```